# How to render a dependency(project.tasks) in a two model (project + task) json result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given that each project has_many `:tasks`, I hope to render the project.task within the json result.

However, the json output also include a list of individual tasks as part of the result. See below:

```
@tasks = Task.all.reject do |i|
  i.project.inbox == false || i.completion_status == 100
end

@projects = Project.all.reverse.reject do |i|
  i.inbox == true || i.completion_status == 100
end

@all = @tasks + @projects

respond_to do |format|
  format.html 
  format.json { paginate json: @all.sort_by(&:created_at).reverse, 
                per_page: 25 }
end
```

This means that if I simply include:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html 
  format.json { paginate json: @all.sort_by(&:created_at).reverse, 
                        :include => [:tasks => {:only => :id}],
                per_page: 25 }
end
```

Rails will throw an error of `undefined method tasks for Task:0x007fa0ad8d3858` since tasks does not have a task method.

How can I have the project.tasks appear in a json result which also include individual tasks result? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) gem. After installing you can define a serializer for `Project` model like so:

```
class ProjectSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :created_at, :tasks

  def tasks
    object.tasks.map(&:id)
  end
end
```

*Note: There might be any attributes you need. It's just an example.*

Then you can do:

```
@projects = Project.all.reverse.reject do |i|
  i.inbox == true || i.completion_status == 100
end

serialized_projects = ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(@projects, each_serializer: ProjectSerializer).as_json
```

It will return you an array:

```
[{:id => 1, :created_at => "2017-07-13 08:13:20", tasks => [1, 2, 3, ...]}, ...]
```

Then for json response you can concat `@tasks` and `serialized_projects`:

```
all_for_json = @tasks + serialized_projects
```

And finally you can sort it like this:

```
all_for_json.sort_by { |record| record[:created_at] }.reverse
```

*Note that you should do exactly `record[:created_at]`, because projects are hashes, not active record models.*

**But I don't think this is a good idea to mix hashes and active record models in one array. So there is another solution.**

You can also define a serializer for `Task` model:

```
class TaskSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :created_at
end
```

*Note: There might be any attributes you need. It's just an example.*

And override code like this:

```
@tasks = Task.all.reject do |i|
  i.project.inbox == false || i.completion_status == 100
end

@projects = Project.all.reverse.reject do |i|
  i.inbox == true || i.completion_status == 100
end

respond_to do |format|
  format.html do
    @all = @tasks + @projects
  end

  format.json do
    serialized_tasks = ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(@tasks, each_serializer: TaskSerializer).as_json
    serialized_projects = ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(@projects, each_serializer: ProjectSerializer).as_json

    all_serialized = serialized_tasks + serialized_projects

    paginate json: all_serialized.sort_by { |record| record[:created_at] }.reverse, per_page: 25
  end
end
```

To DRY your code, you can put

```
ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(...).as_json
```

to separate method. For example:

```
def serialize_collection(collection, each_serializer)
  ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(collection, each_serializer: each_serializer).as_json
end
```

And do serializations like this:

```
serialized_tasks = serialize_collection(@tasks, TaskSerializer) 
serialized_projects = serialize_collection(@projects, ProjectSerializer)
```

Profits of this solution:

1. You don't mix active record models and hashes in one array.
2. You can easily define via serializers which attributes and associations to include and set custom names for them.